# How to get the sender of an e-mail in EWS MAPI?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm accessing all e-mails from Exchange Server by code using the EWS Managed API. 
I loop over all the items in the mailbox and load them:

`item.Load()`

I need to know the sender of the item/e-mail message. But I don't know how to access the property that has the information. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was my solution:

```
EmailMessage mes = (EmailMessage)item;
TextBox1.Text = mes.Sender.Name;
```

After loading the item I just casted it to `EmailMessage` to get access to the properties and methods.