# C# ews sender address

Tags: c#, email, exchangewebservices, sender, email-address

I am trying to get specific information about an email (messageID, mailboxname, date, from, to, subject, body, seq, date_inserted_db, hasattachment) and I can successfully get them using either the item.whatever method or using emailMessage to cast the item like shown in [How to get the sender of an e-mail in EWS MAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233461/how-can-i-get-the-sender-of-a-mail-in-ews-mapi). How can i get the actually email address of the sender?

```
EmailMessage mes = (EmailMessage)item;
String sender = mes.Sender.Name;
```

This gives me something like "toosweetnitemare" instead of toosweetnitemare@whatever.com. I have also tried

```
System.Web.Mail.MailMessage receivedMessage = GetMail();
string replyTo = receivedMessage.From;
```

But that wouldnt play nice with my code and kept telling me to change my framework version. Strange and I dont want to use it.

I want the address using either EWS or casting. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're probably looking for

```
String sender = mes.Sender.Address;
```

Comment: You are correct I was. Sorry i figured it out late last night and forgot to update this. Thanks for the help though!